# Reading environment variables in Monit Configuration

Tags: linux, configuration, monit

How can I read environment variable inside monit configuration? For example, I have the following.

```
...
alert ~page_me@domain.com only on { timeout }
```

But, I want different email address in different environments and want to load it from the environment variable (e.g. $HOME) of the machine.

Comment: As a suggestion only, you can use include files (see https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#INCLUDE-FILES) to split the configuration into a location or system and an application specific part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice idea, but such a function is not available yet.
You can not do this!